# Do I have to store sentry public key in an .env file

Tags: sentry

Everything is more or less said in the title. When I start the sentry sdk I have a dsn string that I have to write in my code to initialize it. I was wondering if I can hardcode this string or if I have to store it somewhere else. I wonder if it is dangerous or not. Thanks in advance.

Example of initialization: `Sentry.init("https://examplePublicKey@o0.ingest.sentry.io/0")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a public address. The DSN string only allows events to be sent to a Sentry project. It doesn't give access to retrieve any data from it nor it can be used to execute any operation on your behalf. If for some reason it gets abused (bogus events start coming in), you can easily discard that DSN and create a new one.